# After changing version code and name app is not working

Tags: android

I am developing an android app where minimum is 16 and 25.When I change the version code and version name in projects `Structure->flavor -> version code- 2` and `version name- 2.0` its works fine in marshmallow, but it does not run in older versions like kitkat it shows an error message like

> app is stop working

what to do ?

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow! We'd love to help you, but you don't provide a lot of information that would allow us to help :(. Please include what the app does, what error message you are getting, and the part of the code that is broken (or a small example, preferably not the whole thing). Once you've edited your post with this info, you should be on your way to receiving great answers!

Answer (score 0):

**Change your manifest file. Remove target sdk line**. If u write target 19 then it will be fine on kitkat but whenever 20 or more than that will come then same prob will arrive again, so just delete target sdk.

Comment: its not working.. i hv removed the target sdk 25 line from build.gradle and manifest. nothing is working. my minimum sdf is 16 and maximum is 25

Comment: Can you try with min sdk 15

Comment: app is not working below 21 . what it had to do with minimum sdk?

Comment: If you want to run app above 21 then why are you targeting kitkat version? Please go through [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

Comment: i have not taken target as kitkat. my min is 16 compile is 25 and target is 25 . when i run the app in kitkat version of android it shows error.

Comment: thanks i got it. one other operation causing this problem.